# Make Div appear around chirstmas period

Tags: css, animation, effects

I wanted to ask a question, I know next to nothing about html and I wanted to apply a snow type effect on a page. I got code from here and added it but I'd like to make it so it appears from the 1st of november to 31st of December and disspears afterwards automatically and comes back again next year. Could someone please help me figure out how I can do that.

codepen.io/codeconvey/pen/xRzQay

Also this might be a question for the person who made this but is there a quick way to make it snow more flakes?

Thanks!

Comment: You can achieve that with JavaScript. Just get the current date and check if it is between 1st of November and 31st of December

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to get the current date with JS and check if it is between 1st of November and 31st of December. In short, you only need the month. JS calculates the month with zero index (January is 0, December is 11). In your case, you only need to check if the month is 10 or 11 (no need to check for day and year)

```js
/* https://pajasevi.github.io/CSSnowflakes/ */

if (new Date().getMonth() == 10 || new Date().getMonth() == 11) {
  var children = document.getElementById('snowflakes').children;
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].classList.add('snowflake');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: red;
}


/* customizable snowflake styling */

.snowflake {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes snowflakes-fall {
  0% {
    top: -10%
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes snowflakes-shake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
    transform: translateX(80px)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
}

@keyframes snowflakes-fall {
  0% {
    top: -10%
  }
  100% {
    top: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes snowflakes-shake {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(80px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px)
  }
}

.snowflake {
  position: fixed;
  top: -10%;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-animation-name: snowflakes-fall, snowflakes-shake;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s, 3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running, running;
  animation-name: snowflakes-fall, snowflakes-shake;
  animation-duration: 10s, 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear, ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
  animation-play-state: running, running
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(0) {
  left: 1%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s, 0s
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 10%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s, 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s, 1s
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 20%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s, .5s;
  animation-delay: 6s, .5s
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 30%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s, 2s;
  animation-delay: 4s, 2s
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 40%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s, 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s, 2s
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s, 3s;
  animation-delay: 8s, 3s
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(6) {
  left: 60%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s, 2s;
  animation-delay: 6s, 2s
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(7) {
  left: 70%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s, 1s;
  animation-delay: 2.5s, 1s
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(8) {
  left: 80%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s, 0s;
  animation-delay: 1s, 0s
}

.snowflake:nth-of-type(9) {
  left: 90%;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s, 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 3s, 1.5s
}


/* Demo Purpose Only*/

.demo {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.demo a {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="snowflakes" aria-hidden="true">
  <div>
    ❅
  </div>
  <div>
    ❅
  </div>
  <div>
    ❆
  </div>
  <div>
    ❄
  </div>
  <div>
    ❅
  </div>
  <div>
    ❆
  </div>
  <div>
    ❄
  </div>
  <div>
    ❅
  </div>
  <div>
    ❆
  </div>
  <div>
    ❄
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sara, sorry this might seem like a stupid question but i'm still very new at this. If /* customizable snowflake styling */
goes under <style> where does this part go? if (new Date().getMonth() == 10 || new Date().getMonth() == 11) {
  var children = document.getElementById('snowflakes').children;
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].classList.add('snowflake');
  }
}

Comment: the JS goes into `<script></script>` tag
If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted

Comment: sorry I meant does it go into the body or is it part of style. When I tired it with 11 || new Date().getMonth() == 0) it still showed it so I may not have put it in the correct place

Comment: It goes into separate tag (script) in the body. I've attached a [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/h51AmadgWr6zL3dm?preview) for your reference

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. There is a slight problem though if i make the animation stop e.g. by changing   if (new Date().getMonth() == 11 || new Date().getMonth() == 0) {
  var children = document.getElementById('snowflakes').children;
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].classList.add('snowflake');       It makes the snowflakes visible without an animation. Is there a way to fix that? sorry to trouble you.

Comment: `new Date().getMonth() == 0)` is incorrect. It should be `new Date().getMonth() == 10)` (0 month is January), that's why your snowflakes are visible but without animation

Answer (score 0):

```
    var d = new Date()

if(d.getMonth() < 10){ //starts counting from 0
  var snows = document.getElementById("snows");
  snows.remove();
}
```

I also added an id to your snowflake div.

You can increase the amount of snowflakes by adding more

```
<div class="snowflake">
  ❄
  </div>
```

into your html.